# ENCTYPE MULTIPART form Data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to know if it's possible to have a 'switch system' on the enctype of a form I explain : I have a form with a no required $_Files.. If I have an uploader file, everything is working but if I've not, I' receive an empty mail but with the good headers. I think its because of the enctype and I'don't know how to have an action on.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: you wanna to say if enctype is multipart/form-data and no files are uploaded then it's creating problem,so you wanna auto-detect  for that and change enctype accordingly....am i correct???

Answer (score 0):

For many of our every day UI problems, jQuery can be one handy solution...
I have prepared this simple html form:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="myActionFile.php">
    <div>First Name <span>*</span><input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"></div>
        <div>Last Name <span>*</span><input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"></div>
    <div>Your File: <input class="form-control" type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"></div>
    <div><button class="btn pull-right" id="submit">SEND</button></div>
</form>
```

As you can see in the "form" tag the 'enctype' is not included. That will be taken care of by javascript (jQuery actually):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#firstname').val().length < 1){$('#firstname').css('background-color', '#ffc9c9').prop('placeholder', 'Required');}
    if($('#lastname').val().length < 1){$('#lastname').css('background-color', '#ffc9c9').prop('placeholder', 'Required');}else{
        var fileData = $('#myfile').val();
        if(fileData != ""){ //if file has been selected:
            $('#myform').prop('enctype', 'multipart/form-data').submit();
        }else{ //if NO file selected:
            $('#myform').prop('enctype', 'text/plain').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

The above code

1. checks if the required fields (firstname, lastname) are not blank
2. checks the "file" input -if it is blank or not- and assigns the form the proper "enctype"
3. and finally, submits the form

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8y2y5z4s/